# How do I load the DiskManagement framework in single user mode?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, single-user

From single-user mode in OS X 10.5, I want to run

```
diskutil repairPermissions /
```

but I get an error:

```
Unable to run because unable to use the DiskManagement framework
...
```

Is there a way to load the DiskManagement framework or otherwise repair permissions in single user mode?

Comment: Which version of OS X? If you are just looking to run repair permissions, you could boot into recovery mode and run Disk Utility but I don't know if you have to be in single user mode for another operation or don't have recovery HD available..

Comment: 10.5.8. There is no option to upgrade. Thanks for reminding me about the recovery mode option. I'd still like to know how in single user mode since I occasionally come across clients that are so messed up they can't boot except into single-user mode.

Comment: I edited the post. There is no recovery mode before 10.7 lion so you would need to install a second OS if we can't get you an answer in single user mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Disk Utility Repair Permissions command is just a front end for the [repair_packages](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/repair_packages.8.html) program.

Use this:

```
 /usr/libexec/repair_packages --repair --standard-pkgs
```

Suggestion: run `/sbin/mount -uw /`  prior to running the above command.  Sometimes the disc may be mounted as read only and the command above will not work until you mount it with write permissions. You will be then able to successfully restore file permissions using the command after mounting the disk as writeable. The command ran for over two hours.

Comment: When I run that command, I just get "IFDBFilesInGroupOnTarget() = 10000003, -1073742432". It happens in less than a second, so I doubt permissions are actually being corrected since this is usually a 15 minute procedure.

Comment: @labyrinth I'm sorry, when I answered this I don't think you specified the OS version. I see now that you are running the ancient version Mac OS X 10.5. This command only works on OS X 10.6 or later. Any chance you could upgrade or is this a PowerPC system?

Comment: No, no upgrades available or obtainable. As a workaround, I used a 10.5 OS X install disk to boot into the installation screen and ran disk utility from that.

Comment: On MBP 2011 with MacOs ver.10.11.6 this didn't work for me either.. operation not permitted it says, even with `/sbin/mount -uw /`

Answer (score 0):

And if I remember correctly when you boot into single user mode there are instructions on the screen for mounting the filesystem and running FSCK.

Go ahead and do that and if it finishes and says "** file system was modified**" (or something similar) run it again until you don't get that message after running FSCK.

When done just type reboot

Comment: Ummm... fsck deals on a lower level, finding filesystem inconsistencies. I'm wanting to repair permissions, and perms work in a distinct, higher-level subsystem. fsck isn't going to help in this case.

Answer (score -2):

I find many times it relates to disc space.
reboot holding down **CMD + S**  (safe mode )
once on the command line, issue a **df -h** command to view disc usage.
if low on disc you may issue another command for finding big files and deleting some:
**sudo find / -size +500000 -print** (will display files bigger than 500 MB)
this might take some time so sit back for a while.
when done , you will find a list of files with the full path to them for example:
/Volumes/Data/Stuff/Movies/Star Wars Episode IV A New Hope.mp4

you can then issue the rm -rf for example, you want to make space on your disc by removing the star wars movie you just found:
rm -rf /Volumes/Data/Stuff/Movies/Star Wars Episode IV A New Hope.mp4

thats it
try this out then once back online , please make sure you have a time-machine backup (with a Qnap NAS or a time-capsule machine) or some good secure cloud backup.

Comment: In general, this isn't bad advice, but then you tell people to use -rf flags for deleting files, where a small mistake could cause massive damage.  Please at least remove at least the -r flag from your suggestion, since the user is going to be trying to delete files, not folders.